# Can Revenue Act be second referenced as the Act?

Tags: proper-nouns, capitalization

Question: When you **first reference** Revenue Act or Budget Act because it names a specific act and you **second reference** the same Act -can I shorten it by referring to Revenue Act or Budget Act as the Act?

Comment: Probably. Can you give a paragraph of so of context?  Just proofread to check it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, after an act has been cited, and there's no other act it could mean in the context, you can just say, "the act"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal practice, unless, and sometimes even if, there is some other Act being referred to in the same context.

For brevity, particularly where  has a long name, repeated references are normally shortened as much as possible, both in writing and in speech.

In very formal prose, it is normal practice to do this abbreviation only after explicitly saying so, for example:
"The Very-Long-Winded Act to prevent something terrible (hereinafter: 'The Act')"